# Checkbox statuses not persisted in simple vue.js questionnaire app

Tags: javascript, checkbox, vue.js, frontend, reactive-programming

I wrote this simple questionnaire app example: https://jsfiddle.net/neydmo34/ but I have problem with checkboxes loosing its state when user clicks buttons "Next" and "Back".

For example, if user performs this actions:

1. answer with "Lisp" on first question,
2. click "Next",
3. answer with "Bill Gates" on second question,
4. click "Back",
5. click "Next",

then you'll see that **the "Bill Gates" checkbox will not be checked anymore**, despite the fact that backing array userAnswers is correctly updated.

I cannot understand why that's happen and what I should change in my code to made it work correctly.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Questionnaire</title>
<script src="vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Questionnaire</h1>
<div id="app">
  <p><b>Question {{ currQuestionIndex + 1 }})</b> {{ currQuestion.text }}</p>
  <div v-for="ans in currQuestion.answers">
    <input type="radio"
           :name="currQuestionIndex"
           :value="ans"
           v-model="userAnswers[currQuestionIndex]" />
    <label :for="ans">{{ ans }}</label><br>
  </div>
  <p>
  <button @click="goBack">Back</button>
  <button @click="goNext">Next</button>
  </p>
  userAnswers = {{ userAnswers }}
</div>
</body>
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currQuestionIndex: 0,
    questions: [
        {text: "What's the name of most powerful programming language?",
         answers: ['Java', 'C#', 'Lisp', 'Haskell']
        },
        {text: 'Who is Microsoft founder?',
         answers: ['Bill Gates', 'Richard Stallman', 'Steve Jobs']
        },
        {text: 'What type of software do you like most?',
         answers: ['open source', 'closed source', 'public domain']
        },
        {text: 'The best computing company is:',
         answers: ['IBM', 'Microsoft', 'Google']
        },
    ],

    userAnswers: [null, null, null, null]
  },

  computed: {
    currQuestion: function () {
        return this.questions[this.currQuestionIndex];
    }
  },

  methods: {
    goNext: function(e) {
        var next = this.currQuestionIndex + 1;
        if (next >= this.questions.length) {
            alert("Ok, your answers are: " + this.userAnswers);
        } else {
            this.currQuestionIndex = next;
        }
    },
    goBack: function(e) {
        var previous = this.currQuestionIndex - 1;
        if (previous >= 0) {
            this.currQuestionIndex = previous;
        }
    }
  }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: It works for me...

Comment: Did you tried those 5 steps indicated in my question?

Comment: Yes, and the checkboxes values are saved. What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Comment: Cristy, try this: on first questions click "Java", then click "Next", then click "Richard Stallman", then click "Back" and you'll see that "Java" checkbox on the first question is not retained.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currQuestionIndex: 0,
    questions: [
        {text: "What's the most powerful programming language?",
         answers: ['Java', 'Scheme', 'Lisp', 'Haskell']
        },
        {text: 'Who is Microsoft founder?',
         answers: ['Bill Gates', 'Richard Stallman', 'Steve Jobs']
        },
        {text: 'What type of software do you like most?',
         answers: ['open source', 'closed source', 'public domain']
        },
        {text: 'The best computing company is:',
         answers: ['IBM', 'Microsoft', 'Google']
        },
    ],
    
    userAnswers: [null, null, null, null]
  },
  
  computed: {
    currQuestion: function () {
        return this.questions[this.currQuestionIndex];
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    goNext: function(e) {
        var next = this.currQuestionIndex + 1;
        if (next >= this.questions.length) {
            alert("OK, your answers are: " + this.userAnswers);
        } else {
            this.currQuestionIndex = next;
        }
    },
    goBack: function(e) {
        var previous = this.currQuestionIndex - 1;
        if (previous >= 0) {
            this.currQuestionIndex = previous;
        }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.js"></script>
<h1>Questionnaire</h1>
<div id="app">
  <p><b>Question {{ currQuestionIndex + 1 }})</b> {{ currQuestion.text }}</p>
  <div v-for="ans in currQuestion.answers" :key="ans">
    <input type="radio" :name="currQuestionIndex" :value="ans" v-model="userAnswers[currQuestionIndex]" />
    <label :for="ans">{{ ans }}</label><br>
  </div>
  <p>
  <button @click="goBack">Back</button>
  <button @click="goNext">Next</button>
  </p>
  userAnswers = {{ userAnswers }}
</div>
```

[You need a key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key).

> When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with `v-for`, it by
> default uses an “in-place patch” strategy. If the order of the data
> items has changed, instead of moving the DOM elements to match the
> order of the items, Vue will simply patch each element in-place and
> make sure it reflects what should be rendered at that particular
> index. This is similar to the behavior of `track-by="$index"` in Vue
> 1.x.

> This default mode is efficient, but only suitable **when your list render output does not rely on child component state or temporary DOM
> state (e.g. form input values).**
>
> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus
> reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique `key`
> attribute for each item.

Since each answer is unique in your form, you can use `:key="ans"`.

**Update**: added snippet copied in from Cristy's fiddle.

Comment: still don't work. To see why, try this: try this: on first questions click "Java", then click "Next", then click "Richard Stallman", then click "Back" and you'll see that "Java" checkbox on the first question is not retained.

Comment: @xenax Try the snippet that is now part of my answer.

Comment: @RoY J Thanx, now it seems to work (though I don't have a clue why... I have to learn Vue.js thoroughly :(